# Node-Webkit Application: Loading thousands of images from disk

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, memory, node-webkit

I have created a node-webkit application that loads thousands of images (7,480 to be exact) from disk into an HTML table. After about 3500 images, the loading stops. In the console, I see `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`. According to Task Manager, the memory (private working set) for my app is at around 1.37 GB when this happens. How can I prevent this from happening? Is there a way for me to increase this limit? What additional details should I provide to receive help?

Comment: The real question here is why you need to load all of them at once? Only load into your UI what any user can reasonably take in at any one time.

Comment: The images show different points on a surface that is undergoing a mechanical process. The user needs to be able to see all of them to identify certain defects. Is there a way for me to load images when they are in view, and "unload" them when they aren't?

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, there is a way, but how you implement that depends on how you're putting all this together. In effect you want some sort of JIT loading of the imagery removing and adding as the user moves around the "viewport". It's more performant than loading all at once.

Answer (score 1):

In the past when i have faced a similar problem, i held the images in memory, and inserted them into the dom as they scrolled into view.

I created two queues one for images not the scroll down to, and one for images that have been scrolled past. this way only images that are visible are present in the page.

If the download time is an issue try loading them into memory and see what happens, there is a chance the limit you have encountered is about placing images in the dom, and not necessarily loading the images into memory, worth a try.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

```
var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
```

Comment: Could you tell me more about how you inserted them as they scrolled into view? This is exactly what I'm looking for. Also, I used this method to load the images into memory: `function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < imgFiles.length; i++) {
     images[i] = new Image();
     images[i].src = preload.arguments[i];
    }
   }` but I'm still seeing `ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES` in the console. The array, however, seems to be fully populated.

Comment: You were right about the limit I encountered being about placing images in the DOM. I ended up using this lazy-loading plugin: http://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/

Comment: awesome, the mechanism for putting them in the page was basically, an array of before, and an array of after, then calculate the scroll position of each element, and remove them from the page as they scroll out of view, and place the new ones in the page as you are about to scroll them into view